# Error reading data using python array fromfile

Tags: python, binaryfiles, pcap

I´m trying read a binary pcap file in Python 2.7.

```
import array
f = open('unit_46_Monterey_subset.pcap')
bin = array.array('B')
bin.fromfile(f, 1206)
```

The file is 12.640.024 bytes sized.

When I run it, I´m getting the error message: EOFError: 'not enough items in file'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're `opening` your file in the wrong mode: instead of `'r'` (the default), you need to open with `'rb'`, which is for reading binary files. This should work:

```
import array
f = open('unit_46_Monterey_subset.pcap', 'rb')  # notice the 2nd argument
bin = array.array('B')
bin.fromfile(f, 1206)
```

And of course, don't forget to `close` the file when you're done:

```
f.close()
```